# Typing my network password without keyboard

Tags: wireless

I have a device with only one USB port (BeagleBone Black), and I would like to connect to a WiFi network on it. I recently purchased an ASUS USB N-13, which works out of the box on Ubuntu 14.04. The device comes on, but the problem is that since it takes up my only USB port, I can't use a keyboard to connect to my password-protected network, and if I connect to the network via ethernet cable, the wireless receiver does not get activated (No LED lit up).

Is there any way to solve this issue without purchasing a USB hub? My preferred solution would be to enable the wireless receiver while I have an ethernet cable plugged in, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this:

- Make network manager remember your password. This is particularly useful if you connect yourself to the same networks.
- Use the [on-screen keyboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_keyboard) to type the password.
- Purchase that hub. By the specifications of Beagle, I would look for one that has its own power source.
- Use SSH to connect to the device to type the password.
- This a variant of the first, but you could save your password, ESSID, etc. in `/etc/networking/interfaces`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I just got it working with help from this forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1704257 (going the /etc/networking/interfaces route). It's working great so far!

Answer (score 3):

Following Braiam's advice, I got the issue fixed by editing my /etc/networking/interfaces file. I added the following code:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.1.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.x

wireless-essid <WIFI ESSID>
wireless-key <WIFI PASSWORD>
```

and then rebooting the system.